# what does this line of code mean - elif left[0] > right[0]:?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and would appreciate any help i can

I'm looking at this code :

```
  if left[0] < right[0]:
            result.append(left[0])
            left = left[1:]
        elif left[0] > right[0]:
            result.append(right[0])
            right = right[1:]
        max_iter -= 1
```

it doesn't make sense what it means , its about changing the order of numbers in a sequence to ascending order but what does [0] mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list, like `s = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']`, then you can print out `print(s[0])`, which will output `H`, as it is the first element in the list (Remember, programming languages start counting at 0, so [0] means the first element).

Further, you can print out multiple elements of a list by using `print(s[1:6])` which will print out `['e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ']`, as these are the second two seventh elements.

You can also use `print(s[1:])` which will print from the second element to the end (`['e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!']`) or `print(s[:6])` to print from the start to the seventh character (`['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ']`)

Answer (score 0):

[0] means the element at 0 index. Index always starts from 0. In iterable datatypes, index represents the position of the element. For example, if we have a list say l=[1,2,3,4,5]. Here, 1,2,3,4,5 are elements but the positions i.e. the index starts from zero. So the index value of 1 is 0, index of 2 is 1 index of 3 is 2 and so on. If we have another example say x=["hi","go","come","speak"], then the index value of "hi" is 0, index of "go" is 1, index of "come" is 2 and index of "speak" is 3. Now, to acces the 3rd element (which is at 2nd index) we use `<variable>[<index>]` . Here, to acces the 3rd element i.e. "come", we use x[2]